# Missing Projects tab from the gerrit UI

Tags: git, gerrit

We're setting a new gerrit server on UBUBTU machine. The gerrit version is 3.0.1. 
We're a small team and the server is configured without authentication (authentication type DEVELOPMENT_BECOME_ANY_ACCOUNT).
When looking at the UI, there is no "Project" tab.
I added a new project using the command line ssh -p 29418  gerrit create-project .
Looking at the server directories, I can see the project directory under the git/ directory, but the "Project" tab is till missing.

The gerrit config file looks like:

```
[gerrit]
        basePath = git
        canonicalWebUrl = http://<IP>:8080/
        serverId = <>
[database]
        type = POSTGRESQL
        database = reviewdb
        hostname = localhost
        username = postgres
[container]
        javaOptions = "-Dflogger.backend_factory=com.google.common.flogger.backend.log4j.Log4jBa  ckendFactory#getInstance"
        javaOptions = "-Dflogger.logging_context=com.google.gerrit.server.logging.LoggingContext#getInstance"`enter code here`
        user = root
        javaHome = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
[index]
        type = LUCENE
[auth]
        type = DEVELOPMENT_BECOME_ANY_ACCOUNT
[receive]
        enableSignedPush = true
[sendemail]
        smtpServer = localhost
[sshd]
        listenAddress = *:29418
[httpd]
        listenUrl = http://<IP>:8080/
[cache]
        directory = cache
```

The UI image looks like 
[WebUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMlqs.jpg)

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There's no "Projects" tab in Gerrit 3.0.1, what you're looking for is the "Browse > Repositories" menu, the project created with "ssh -p 29418 gerrit create-project" command must be showed there.

See more info at the [Gerrit documentation](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/), pay special attention to the [Project Owner Guide](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/intro-project-owner.html) item.

---

Before version 2.16, "Repositories" was called "Projects" and it was renamed with change [142193](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/c/gerrit/+/142193) / Issue [7754](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=7754). I believe you may have been looking at older documentation when you were looking for "Projects"?

Comment: Thanks, the repositories tab show the new project.
However, I'm having other problems with pushing code and configuration. Can you recommend a site/guide/manual for dummies on how to configure gerrit?
I worked with gerrit as a user, but never as the project owner/creator.

Comment: I added the Gerrit documentation link in the answer, I think is the best way to start.